# TypeError: i.hasOwnProperty is not a function in QA enviroment

Tags: javascript

In our customer site we´re using Popover/tooltip from bootrap in a form. It works fine locally but in our QA-enviroment it generates a javascript error:
TypeError: i.hasOwnProperty is not a function

The code is exactly the same in both enviroment. Does anybody have a clue on what could be wrong or where I should start looking?

Thanks for your answers

Comment: In which element you exactly use tooltip? Check if there is a such method appear in both environments by opening up chrome debugger and breaking on all exceptions.